# Managing states of multiple widgets via Bloc pattern

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

On my Main page I have 3 buttons: **play video**, **play audio**, **record voice**. All these button widgets use `Bloc` pattern to control its internal state (e.g. changing button Icon when file is playing) but I'm having trouble understanding how to access their states on my Main page because I'd like to disable other buttons when one of them is pressed.

Any recommendation on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global bool variable and can make that variable state to true when any button is pressed, and as soon as your video playback released, you can make that variable to false, and don't forget to make all buttons disable until that variable is true.

Thanks